# npm link causes "extraneous" errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using `npm link` to work on multiple projects that depend on each other. However, whenever I have a link in `node_modules`, I get a bunch of `npm ERR! extraneous: <module@version> <path>` messages when I do `npm list`. How do I make the messages go away?

Example:

```
cd foo_proj
npm link

cd bar_proj
npm link foo_proj

npm list
```

`bar_proj/node_modules` now contains a symlink to `foo_proj`, but `npm list` now displays a bunch of errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`npm ERR! extraneous` means a package is installed but is not listed in your project's `package.json`.

Since you're listing packages that have been installed globally, it's going to give you a lot of extraneous errors that can be simply ignored because most things installed globally will not be in your project's `package.json`

you can use `tree -d ..` command to see the tree structure

Comment: although it's even better to uninstall them globally and instead install them locally (since npm dedupes anyway, so you don't end up with actual duplicate copies across projects).

Comment: Mike - The issue is whether I use npm link (which adds the module globally) or symlink my other project directly, npm still complains because the other project has its own set of node_modules